# Why do mailto links in Chrome conflict with POST requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, jquery

I'm not entirely sure the question is correct but here's the situation.
I have a webpage with two POST requests, which are open for some time (the response isn't suppose to come right away) while I can be doing other things on the page. I also have a mailto link on the page. For some reason in Chrome, when I click that link, the two requests immediately return an error. I also noticed that the console in Chrome shows the mailto link as a GET request event (when it's clicked). What is going on here? Even if Chrome treats mailto links as requests, why should it conflict with any other requests on the page?

In Firefox the mailto link has zero affect on the requests, they just keep working and waiting on server response. Also, the link itself doesn't seem to be a request of any sort. BTW, the mailto opens up an Outlook message window (and that part works fine in Chrome, just the requests fail).

Also just in case, I'm using jQuery $.ajax to initiate the requests.

It was pointed out that perhaps Chrome treats a mailto link like a regular, at least in part, and so has some of the side effects. So then the question becomes how do I combine a mailto link with request on the page? I can't replace the link with a form.

Comment: Posting the code may be more helpful.

Comment: Not sure what I can post that would help. The mailto link is completely mundane. And the $.ajax requests are also completely plain, in fact they started out as copy-paste from jQuery's site. The only unusual thing about them is that the response doesn't come right away. They both get sent on domready and just sort of sit there waiting for server response.

Comment: It also cancels GET requests (such as if you have logic to track events).

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue recently. This actually happens with mailto: or any other app URI in Chrome. The solution I used was to load the URL in an iframe:

```
$('body').append('<iframe id="mailto-launcher"></iframe>');
$('#mailto-launcher').get(0).contentWindow.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=test';
```

You can also style that iframe so that is it rendered off the page (using absolute positioning, etc). This will launch the mail client and still keep your document's AJAX requests alive.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics support suggests to capture link clicks, send request to GA, wait 100ms and then update the URL. 100ms should be sufficient for tracking request to complete. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

The example is clunky, following is a modified version that handles all links automatically (also those created with javascript/loaded with AJAX):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function trackOutboundLink(event){
    var url = event.currentTarget.href;
    try {
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound Links' , url]);
    } catch(err){}

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.location.href = url;
    }, 100);

    return false;
  }

  $(document).on('click', 'a[href]', trackOutboundLink);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it's possible that Chrome treats clicking `mailto` links as navigating to a new page.

Has all the side-effects of it, but none of the real effects (like reloading the page.)

Comment: Hmmm, this could in fact be that. But that would be a bit stupid wouldn't it. Why would it treat it like that?

Comment: @ilia: Why would it not? Just because the request happens to use a handler other than `http` or `https`? You've only ever been allowed to have one basic request going on a page at a time. Clicking a link cancels the loading through some other link you just clicked on previously.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea...Maybe Chrome simply handles them differently, maybe it was easier (development wise) to make them work like a download works (e.g. running the default email handler.) Edit: Or maybe it's what Tomalak said. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak "Just because the request happens to use a handler other than http or https?" Well yeah! :) It's not a standard link, it doesn't behave (at least in part) like a standard link, so it shouldn't be causing this problem. I actually tried adding target blank to it and it works but it also opens a new blank tab. *sigh*

Comment: @ilia: It's _completely_ a standard link.

Answer (score 0):

This issue prevented me from sending event to Google Analytics when email link was clicked.

As a workaround I changed target of mailto: links to _blank. This causes the browser to open an empty tab before opening Mail.app, but GA integration works now.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, POSTs to mixpanel were cancelled. Our workaround was to invoke the mailto: link using a setTimeout of 1 second, it works just fine. Not nice, tough, but at 10pm on Friday at the office it sounded kind of allright :)